# Render view dynamically based on model in Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two domain classes , one is **FlatClass** and other is **PGClass**. Based on these two i have created a ViewModel. If user has selected **Flat radio button** from UI then **FlatClass** will get populated, otherwise on selection of **PG radio button** the **PGClass** will get populated. And on view i am using this **ViewModel**. Is is good to load and pass the properties of other class which he has not selected in **ViewModel** in view from performance point view or we can **suppress or obselete** the properties of non- selected class based on condition ?? . I don't want to create  two partial views, how will i render the UI based on dynamic selection of Model from controller in single partial view ?

Comment: can you provide an example code plz?

Comment: Bellash : Actually this is the  scenario of  my application that i need to implement. So i don't have the code for it now.

Comment: Are you displaying the view for `FlatClass` and `PGClass` in the same view as the radio buttons (in which case you need javascript/jquery to respond to client side events).

Comment: StephenMuecke : Yes.  On selection of respective radio button  , the div will be just appended with partial view on the same view.

Comment: you can combine both the model or check out this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214439/how-to-combine-two-view-models-in-razor-mvc-asp-net

Comment: @naveensemwal, Then you can either render both views inside hidden div elements (and show one or other in response to the user selecting a radio button) or use ajax to call a controller method that returns a partial view based on the selected radio button. Not sure why you _"don't want to create two partial views"_ - which is probably the correct approach using either of these 2 methods

Comment: Stephen Muecke : Fine ...ok. I was just thinking in terms of performance and reusability.

Comment: @naveensemwal, That depends on too many variables which we don't know. Only you can test that yourself. (ps. see how this message starts)

Answer (score 0):

Although the best practice is to use two different partial views with model. But in case you want to implement this with a single partial view, you may create a base class that inherits from both FlatClass and PGClass.

Now you can create a single partial view with this new ViewModel.

```
public class BaseClass
{
   public FlatClass? flat {get; set;}
   public PGClass? pg {get; set;}
}
```

Please note both the objects are Nullable, since you will only be using one of them at a time and other one will be NULL.